# jQuery : There is overlapping in animated elements after using .stop() on mouseover

Tags: jquery

In the below code, when I'm calling stop() the elements upon resume overlap. Hence making the ad banner a total mess. Is there any way where i can do something about it. I've also used jQuery.pause api also and I've searched the Internet but nothing seems to be working. Below is the code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".graph_div").animate({width: "9000px", left: "-606px"}, 11000).delay(2000).fadeOut(500);
$(".star_man").delay(1000).fadeIn(30).animate({width:32, marginRight: "250px"}, 4900);
$(".star_man_end").delay(7500).animate({width: "32px", right: "60px"}, 3500).delay(2000).fadeOut(500);
$(".depressive_man").delay(5500).fadeIn(1).animate({left: "10px"}, 2000).delay(5500).fadeOut(500);
$(".seroquel_content").delay(800).animate({right: "0px"},700).delay(2600).animate({right: "298px"}, 700);
$(".acute_depressive").delay(4800).animate({right: "0px"}, 700).delay(2500).animate({right: "298px"}, 700);
$(".your_patient").delay(9000).animate({right: "0px"}, 700).delay(3200).fadeOut(500);
$(".header_example_text").delay(500).fadeIn(500).delay(8000).fadeOut(500);
$(".header_logo_div").delay(14000).animate({height: 96,top: 8}, 1000);
$(".one_medication").delay(16000).animate({right: "0px"}, 700).delay(3000).animate({right: "298px"}, 700);
$(".depress_man_left").delay(18000).fadeIn(300).delay(1000).fadeOut(500);
$(".star_man_logo,.star_man_shadow").delay(20000).fadeOut(500);
$(".discover_its").delay(22000).animate({right: "0px"}, 700);
$(".depress_man_right").delay(24000).fadeIn(500);
$(".see_the_data").delay(26000).fadeIn(500);



 $(".footer_text").mouseover(function () {
    if(!$(".footer_text").is(":animated")){
            $(".footer_text").animate({
                bottom: 106
            }, 1e3);
        $(".footer_content").animate({
            bottom: 0
            }, 1e3);
        $(".close_btn").animate({
            bottom: 94
            }, 1e3)
        }
    });
    $(".close_btn").click(function () {
        $(".footer_text").animate({
            bottom: -1
        }, 1e3);
        $(".footer_content").animate({
            bottom: -106
        }, 1e3)
        $(".close_btn").animate({
            bottom: -12
        }, 1e3)
    });
    $(".blank_link").fadeIn(0);

$(".footer_text").bind("mouseover",function(){
        $(".graph_div, .star_man, .star_man_end, .depressive_man, .seroquel_content, .acute_depressive, .your_patient, .header_example_text, .header_logo_div, .one_medication, .depress_man_left, .star_man_logo, .star_man_shadow, .discover_its, .depress_man_right, .see_the_data").stop(true,false);
    });
$(".close_btn").click(function(){
    $(".graph_div").animate({width: "10000px", left: "-606px"},11000).delay(2000).fadeOut(500);
    $(".star_man").delay(780).fadeIn(30).animate({width:75, marginRight: "250px"},3300);
    $(".star_man_end").delay(7000).fadeIn(100).delay(2000).fadeOut(500);
    $(".depressive_man").delay(3500).fadeIn(1).animate({left: "10px"},1700).delay(3700).fadeOut(500);
    $(".seroquel_content").delay(400).animate({right: "0px"},700).delay(1400).animate({right: "298px"},700);
    $(".acute_depressive").delay(3000).animate({right: "0px"},700).delay(2000).animate({right: "298px"},700);
    $(".your_patient").delay(6000).animate({right: "0px"},700).delay(2300).fadeOut(500);
    $(".header_example_text").delay(500).fadeIn(500).delay(8000).fadeOut(500);
    $(".header_logo_div").delay(9500).animate({height: 96,top: 8},1000);
    $(".one_medication").delay(10500).animate({right: "0px"},700).delay(1000).animate({right: "298px"},700);
    $(".depress_man_left").delay(11500).fadeIn(300).delay(1000).fadeOut(500);
    $(".star_man_logo,.star_man_shadow").delay(12500).fadeOut(500);
    $(".discover_its").delay(13500).animate({right: "0px"}, 700);
    $(".depress_man_right").delay(14500).fadeIn(500);
    $(".see_the_data").delay(14500).fadeIn(500);
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try assigning a z-index to every one of those classes, have a higher z-index for item's you wish to be seen above others.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp